# Martingal-property of stochastic Integral w.r.t. Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

To Show that $(e^{B_t^1}cos(B_t^2))_{t \in \mathbb{R_+}}$ (where: $B=(B_s^1,B_s^2)$ is a 2-dimensional Brownian Motion) is a Martingal I used Ito's Lemma and showed that this is equal to:
$ 1+ \int_0^t{e^{B_s^1}cos(B_s^2)dB_s^1}-\int_0^t{e^{B_s^1}sin(B_s^2)dB_s^2}$.

How do I show that this is a Martingale?

Best regards

Comment: Why not show directly that, for every $0<s<t$, $$E(X_t\mid\mathcal F_s)=X_sE(e^Y\cos(Z)),$$ where $(Y,Z)$ is i.i.d. centered normal with variance $t-s$?

Comment: for the exponential it is clear how this would work, but how to split the cosine into the needed product?

Comment: Use the addition formula for cosines and the fact that the random variable $\sin(B_t-B_s)$ is centered.

Comment: Thank you. With your hints I was able to Show the Martingale property. But the problem still is how to Show that:$ \mathbb{E}[X_t]<\infty $.
I fear this is trivial, but I still dont see it. I can drop cosine for sure but what about the exponential integrated over the real-line?
Is it the Dominated convergence Theorem ?

Comment: Big problem? The cosine is bounded and $B^1_t$ is centered normal hence you are left with showing that $E(e^{cY})$ is finite for every $c$, with $Y$ standard normal. And you know the PDF of $Y$...

Comment: ok, stupid  question, saw it as u answered. 
thank you for the help!